# Can I change the UINavigationController viewControllers stack?

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I have 3 viewControllers, From the first i go to the second, and from the second to the third.

I want to go from the third view controller back to the first.

One solution I found is to create a custom button and replace the back button, this way I perform my own selector and go back to the firstVC. But the button I created doesnt look like the back button.

So one solution I thought about is:

Once I enter the third view controller, alter the viewControllers arrays in the navigationController removing the second view controller. This way it would go back to the first without changing the back button.

Is this possible? can I change the UINavigationController stack at will?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the details of what you are doing but you want to avoid going back twice when the user expects to go back once with that back button. I would think a good solution would be to have some other action on the view.

So I assume from what you said that if the user goes to that view they need to go back to the start and cannot go back to the second view controller. On the third VC I would hide the back button or the navigation bar completely and then have another button on the view that clearly does some action and then you can just popToRootViewController.

Comment: The secondVC is a VC to make a search and the third to show the results of the search. So when the user is done with the results I wanted him to go back to the main page not the search fields. I will also have a button like "redo Search", but I think the back button should take him back home. Thoughts?

Comment: The search could be a modal view controller which pops up and when your selection occurs it dismisses while pushing onto the stack the result view controller. This sounds like it would be more in line with your user flow and you wouldn't have to do this hack to get this to work.

Comment: I ended up doing as you suggested, using a modal for the search and adding just the result in the stack. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

You can try to remove the  second view controller from the stack and check it. Shouldn't be a problem.

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:self.navigationController.viewControllers];
[array removeObjectAtIndex:1];

self.navigationController.viewControllers = array;
```

Or just use

```
[self.navigationController setViewControllers:array animated:NO];
```

But this is not a recommended approach as the users might get confused. So be careful when you are doing it this way.

Comment: I'll try this in my project.

Answer (score 3):

You can, there is a special method for that - `[UINavigationController setViewControllers:animated:]`.